# Springboot: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I know that this question has been asked before but none of the tips in those answers help. I am completely new to Spring boot and I keep getting this exception. This code runs on another person's computer

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:687)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:967)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:956)
at com.goly.api.start.Application.main(Application.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)

Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start EmbeddedWebApplicationContext due to missing EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean.
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:183)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:156)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:130)
```

**Code**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableScheduling
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"com.goly.api.*"})
//@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration

public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .pathMapping("/")
            .directModelSubstitute(LocalDate.class, String.class)
            .genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class)
            .alternateTypeRules(
                    newRule(typeResolver.resolve(DeferredResult.class,
                                    typeResolver.resolve(ResponseEntity.class, WildcardType.class)),
                            typeResolver.resolve(WildcardType.class)))
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
            .globalResponseMessage(
                    RequestMethod.GET,
                    newArrayList(
                            new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(500).message("500 message")
                                    .responseModel(new ModelRef("Error")).build()));
}
.
.
.

}
```

**POM.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

I use intellij idea 15.0.2

Thank You.

Comment: Have you added "spring boot starter tomcat" to your POm and Enable Autoconfiguration annotation ?

Comment: @Srikanta I have added spring boot starter tomcat like you suggested and enabled autoconfiguration but it still doesn't run. I have now uploaded the pom code and some more of the application class

Comment: Can you try updating the Spring Boot to the latest version 1.3.6. Including the parent.